# Programmatically instantiate a web part page in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, wss-3.0

Is there a simple way to add a web part page to a Sharepoint site programmatically, using either the object model or web services?  It seems straight-forward to create lists and add web parts in this manner, but I can't find an example of how to create a content page.

Edit:  For a plain WSS installation (not MOSS).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to take the route that this isn't a collaboration/publishing site as this isn't mentioned and wss is in the tag list. Pretty clunky in comparison to using a publishing site...

First choose the web part page template you'd like to use from:

> C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS

Then set up a stream to the template and use SPFileCollection.Add() to add it to your document library. For example:

```
string newFilename = "newpage.aspx";
string templateFilename = "spstd1.aspx";
string hive = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\1033\\STS\\DOCTEMP\\SMARTPGS\\");
FileStream stream = new FileStream(hive + templateFilename, FileMode.Open);
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepoint"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPFolder libraryFolder = web.GetFolder("Document Library");
    SPFileCollection files = libraryFolder.Files;
    SPFile newFile = files.Add(newFilename, stream);
}
```

Note: This solution assumes you have the US SharePoint version installed that uses the 1033 language code. Just change the path if different.

Comment: @Alex Is it possible to set the masterpage of newpage.aspx to like SomeMasterPageName.master? How would I include it in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Is it a collaboration/publishing site? If so you can the following blog articles should help:

- [Create and Publish web pages in Publishing SharePoint sites programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/sridhara/archive/2008/06/21/create-and-publish-web-pages-in-publishing-sharepoint-sites-programmatically.aspx)
- [Programmatically create pages - and Add Web Parts](http://www.novolocus.com/2009/04/02/programmatically-create-pages-and-add-web-parts/)
- [Programmatically adding pages to a MOSS Publishing site](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2006/11/15/5168.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to the accepted answer from @AlexAngas is to use the [NewWebPage method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms450826.aspx) of the [SharePoint Foundation RPC Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448359(v=office.14).aspx), as suggested [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10716.sharepoint-2010-create-webpart-page-programmatically.aspx).

```
private static void CreateWebPartPage(this SPWeb web, SPList list, string pageName, int layoutTemplate)
{
    const string newWPPage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                                   "<Batch>" +
                                   "<Method ID=\"0,NewWebPage\">" +
                                    "<SetList Scope=\"Request\">{0}</SetList>" +
                                    "<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">NewWebPage</SetVar>" +
                                    "<SetVar Name=\"ID\">New</SetVar>" +
                                    "<SetVar Name=\"Type\">WebPartPage</SetVar>" +
                                    "<SetVar Name=\"WebPartPageTemplate\">{2}</SetVar>" +
                                    "<SetVar Name=\"Overwrite\">true</SetVar>" +
                                    "<SetVar Name=\"Title\">{1}</SetVar>" +
                                    "</Method>" +
                                     "</Batch>";
    var newWPPageBatchXml = string.Format(newWPPage, list.ID, pageName, layoutTemplate);

    var result = web.ProcessBatchData(newWPPageBatchXml);
}
```

Usage of the above extension method:

```
web.CreateWebPartPage(yourList, "NewPage", 2);
```